# Panel.ZIndex from ItemsControl not working on Canvas in WPF .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, z-index, itemscontrol

I have a Canvas inside a user control.  Inside the canvas I have an Image and an ItemsControl.
eg:   <ItemsControl ... /> 
The items control looks like this:

```
 <ItemsControl 
            x:Name="itmZoneShapes"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LastSelectedZone.PredefinedSelectedLogicalZones}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=RectangleCanvasLeft}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=RectangleCanvasTop}" />
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Path=RectangleCanvasZIndex}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle
                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        Tag="{Binding Path=RectangleName}"
                        Width="{Binding Path=RectangleWidth}"
                        Height="{Binding Path=RectangleHeight}"
                        RadiusX="{Binding Path=RectangleRadiusX}"
                        RadiusY="{Binding Path=RectangleRadiusY}">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush 
                                Color="{Binding Path=RectangleBackgroundColor, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Opacity="0.4"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                        <Rectangle.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding Path=RectangleClip}"/>
                        </Rectangle.Clip>
                    </Rectangle>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The problem is, that the binded Panel.ZIndex somehow works only  in the Canvas from the ItemsPanelTemplate tag.

What I want, is to be able to set Panel.ZIndex for each element inside itemscontrol and show the rectangle over the image or under the image ( based on Panel.ZIndex ).
Right now, I can change only the ItemsControl Panel.ZIndex but the problem is that all the  items in the data template will have the same ZIndex.

Is there a possibility to bind Panel.ZIndex for each item in ItemsControl and be correctly visible in the UI ?

Comment: "*Panel.ZIndex somehow works only in the Canvas from the ItemsPanelTemplate tag*" - this is exactly how it is supposed to work. ZIndex only affects the direct parent Panel of an element, not any other possible Panel up the visual tree. Showing some items above and some below a UI element outside the ItemsControl's visual tree is not possible. You would need to have two ItemsControls.

Comment: *" the problem is that all the items in the data template will have the same ZIndex."*. Then why don't you wrap the content of the DataTemplate into a Grid? It's not really clear what you want.